# Копировать содержимое одной очереди в другую. Java

Tags: java, очередь

В учебнике Шилдта дана реализация трех типов очередей. Необходимо скопировать содержимое одной очереди в другую при помощи статического метода. Даже не знаю, как реализовать этот метод?

Интерфейс:

```
public interface ICharQ{        //интерфейс очереди
    void put (char ch);  //putting symb to queue
    char get(); //извлекаем символы из очереди

    void reset ();

    default char reset1(){return '-';}
}
```

Реализация фиксированной, динамической и кольцевой очередей.

```
class FixedQueue implements ICharQ{
    private char q[]; //массив для элементов очереди
    private int putloc, getloc; //индексы методов

    public FixedQueue (int size){
     q = new char[size+1]; //память для очереди
     putloc=getloc=0; 
    }

    public void put(char ch){
        if (putloc==q.length-1){
          System.out.println(" - Queue is filled");  
          return;  
        }

        putloc++;
        q[putloc]=ch; 
    }

    public char get(){ //извлечение символа из очереди
        if (getloc==putloc){
            System.out.println(" - Queue is empty");
            return (char)0;
        }
        getloc++;
        return q[getloc];
    }

    public void reset(){
        putloc = 0;
        getloc = 0;
    }



}

class CircularQueue implements ICharQ {
  private char q[]; //array for keeping queue elements
  private int putloc, getloc; //indexes of put and get elements

  public CircularQueue(int size){  //пустая очередь на оснвое конструктора
q = new char[size+1];
putloc=getloc=0;
  }

  public void put(char ch){ //очередь полная если putloc на 1 меньше getloc
                            //или если putloc указывает на конец массива, а getloc на начало.
if (putloc+1==getloc |((putloc==q.length-1)&(getloc==0))){
    System.out.println(" - Queue is filled");
    return;
}      

putloc++;
if (putloc==q.length)putloc=0; //array start
q[putloc]=ch;
  }

  //извлекаем символы из очереди
  public char get (){
      if (getloc == putloc){
          System.out.println(" - Queue is empty");
          return (char) 0;
      }
      getloc++;
     if (getloc==q.length) getloc=0;//возвращаемся в начало очереди
     return q[getloc];
  }

  public void reset(){
        putloc = 0;
        getloc = 0;
    }
}

class DynQueue implements ICharQ{
    private char q[];
    private int putloc,getloc;

    public DynQueue(int size){
q=new char[size+1];
putloc=getloc=0;
}
   public void put (char ch){
       if (putloc==q.length-1){
           //увеличить размер очереди 
           char t[]=new char[q.length*2];
           //Скопировать элементы очереди в новую очередь
           for (int i=0; i<q.length; i++)
               t[i] = q[i];
           q = t;
       }
       putloc++;
       q[putloc]=ch;
   } 

   public char get(){
       if (getloc==putloc){
        System.out.println(" - Очередь пуста");
           return(char)0;         
       }     
       getloc++;
       return q[getloc];
   }

   public void reset(){
        putloc = 0;
        getloc = 0;

    }
} 





class IQDemo {

public static void main(String args[]){


  FixedQueue q1 = new FixedQueue(10);
  DynQueue q2 = new DynQueue(5);
  CircularQueue q3 = new CircularQueue(10);

  ICharQ iQ;  

  char ch;
  int i;  


  iQ = q1;
  //помещаем в очередь символы заданного размера
  for (i=0; i<10;i++)
      iQ.put((char)('A'+ i));
  //отображаем очередь
  System.out.print("Содержимое фиксированной очереди: ");
  for (i=0;i<10; i++){
      ch = iQ.get();
      System.out.print(ch);
     }
  System.out.println();

  iQ = q2;
  //помещаем в динамическую очередь
  for (i=0; i <10;i++)
      iQ.put((char)('Z' - i));
  // Отображаем содержимое очереди


  System.out.print("Содержимое динамической очереди: ");
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      // 
      ch = iQ.get();

     System.out.print(ch); 
  }

   System.out.println();


  iQ = q3;
  //помещаем символы в кольчевую очередь
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      iQ.put((char)('A'+i));

//Отображаем содержимое
System.out.print("Содеримое кольцевой очереди: ");
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    ch=iQ.get();
    System.out.print(ch);
}
  System.out.println();

  //еще символов в кольцевую очередь
  for(i=10; i<20;i++)
      iQ.put((char)('A'+i));

  //Отобразить содержимое очереди
  System.out.print("Содержимое кольцевой очереди: ");
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      ch=iQ.get();
      System.out.print(ch);
  }

  System.out.println("\nСохранение и применение данных"+" кольцевой очереди:");

  //помещаем символы в кольцевую очередь и извлекаем
  for(i=0; i<10;i++){
      iQ.put((char)('A'+i));
     // iQ.reset();
      ch=iQ.get();
    //  ch=iQ.reset1();
      System.out.print(ch);

  }
  System.out.println();

}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто создаете функцию которая принимает объекты с интерфейсом ICharQ, передаете в функцию два объекта очереди

```
public static void CopyQ(ICharQ a, ICharQ b) {
...
}
```

А внутри самого метода, просто из одной очереди берете по очереди элементы и вставляете в другую.
Если же вам нужно возвращать копию
То думаю можно принимать один объект перегрузить метод для каждого случая, внутри создавать нужный объект класса, и копировать все туда, после чего возвращать его

```
public static FixedQueue CopyQ(ICharQ a) {
    FixedQueue result;
    ...
    return result;
}

public static DynQueue CopyQ(ICharQ a) {
    DynQueue result;
    ...
    return result;
}

public static CircularQueue CopyQ(ICharQ a) {
    CircularQueue result;
    ...
    return result;
}
```